# Natives' spells and abilities pretty useless on elemental plane of fire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

Let's take a couple of examples: Efreeti and Salamander on the elemental plane of fire. Both have some spell-like abilities which are manifesting their capabilities to use fire. However, it seems that those become pretty powerless on their own plane. I mean, what's the point of being able to cast fireball when  everyone is more or less immune? Even when such effect is greatly enhanced there, it is useless against an adventuring party who has arrived there with proper protections. In addition, thinking about the dynamics between natives, it feels that those kind of abilities would be quite useless against each others  in combat for example, so it seems counter-intuitive that those creatures have developed such abilities in the first place.

Did I miss something when reading through the materials, or is this assessment right?

Comment: What's your problem, here? Are you looking for lore that explains why creatures from a world of fire have the ability to manipulate fire?

Comment: Yes your assessment is right. By the same token, it's amazing that fish are all good swimmers.

Answer (score 0):

On the plane of fire it's easy to imagine that everything is done through fire. Mating rituals probably involve fire, houses will be built from blocks of fire or shaped from flames, flaming discs are probably used in place of a Tenser's Floating Disk. Fireballs on the plane of fire are probably thrown like punches, relying more on the kinetic force than the burning to do non-lethal damage. Imagine the surprise when they visit the material plane and fins their "punches" are so devastating!

Comment: This reads as speculation. Do you have a reference for any of this?